# Using Firebase observeSingleEventOfType synchronously

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use a semaphore to force synchronisation of a Firebase data query so that I can check for an existing item already in the database.

This is the code I have tried to retrieve a snapshot and check for duplicate:

```
    let sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    self.firDB.child("sessions").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        snap = snapshot
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem)
    } )
    // semaphore is never asserted
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

    var isDuplicate : Bool
    repeat {
        sID = genCode()
        isDuplicate =  snap.hasChild(sID)
    } while isDuplicate
```

In this case I need to wait for a snapshot to return before the `isDuplicate` loop, but the semaphore is never fired from the `observeSingleEventOfType` block.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: let me know if u made any progress

Comment: thanks @adolfosrs,  that is definitely a cleaner solution than what I was trying to do, and Ive got that working now, with just minor edits to your code.  I'm still not sure why my semaphore did not work, but Ill go and read up on some other threads to try to work out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be intersted in using a [completion handler](https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/).

```
func findUniqueId(completion:(uniqueId:String)->()) {
    self.firDB.child("sessions").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        var sID = self.genCode()
        while snapshot.hasChild(sID) {
            sID = self.genCode()
        }
        completion(uniqueId:sID)
    })
}
```

Then you will achieve what you are expecting with

```
findUniqueId(){ (uniqueId:String) in
    // this will only be called when findUniqueId trigger completion(sID)...
    print(uniqueId)
    // proceed with you logic...
}
```