# Swift - Firebase search in database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I search for users while typing. However at the end it returns every users.
I don't know why exactly this happens. It seems alright

```
 class func findUsers(text: String)->[User]{
    let user = User()
    var users = [User]()
    ref.child("Users").queryOrderedByChild("name").queryStartingAtValue(text).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        for u in snapshot.children{
            user.name = u.value!["name"] as? String
            user.surname = u.value!["surname"] as? String
            user.email = u.value!["email"] as? String
            user.score = u.value!["score"] as? Int
            user.status = u.value!["status"] as? Int
            user.id = u.value!["id"] as? String
            user.pin = u.value!["pin"] as? String
            users.append(user)
            print(user.name)
        }
    })
    print("users:", users)
    return users
}
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal, representative snippet of your JSON (as text, which you can get by exporting it from the Firebase database console) and the value of `text` at the moment it gives the wrong results?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are using `queryStartingAtValue`. From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_query#a43da151946ea4ba98dbe3053cb2692d3):

> The `FIRDatabaseQuery` instance returned by
>   `queryStartingAtValue:childKey` will respond to events at nodes with a
>   value greater than startValue, or equal to startValue and with a key
>   greater than or equal to childKey.

So keep in mind that if you search for the `name` of an user it will give all the users that have name greater in alphabetic order than the given one. You need to set a `queryEndingAtValue` to limit the query range.

```
ref.child("Users").queryOrderedByChild("name").queryStartingAtValue(text).queryEndingAtValue(text+"\u{f8ff}")
```

[Firebase legacy documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries) is such a good resource to understand on how firebase handle queries. There you will find:

> The f8ff character used in the query above is a very high code point
>   in the Unicode range. Because it is after most regular characters in
>   Unicode, the query matches all values that start with a b.

You might also get interested in [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). [Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) is a node service that integrates elasticsearch and firebase.

---

### Update:

As pointed out in the comments this **won't work if the string you are searching for has upper case characters**. The solution in this case is to have an **additional field in the object with the info you are searching all in lower case**. So if you have `Satoshi Nakamoto` as `name` you would save an additional `nameSearch` property with `satoshi nakamoto`.

And finally make sure your searching string is in lower case too.

---

There is a few other problems with your code.

- You are setting an observer. It will trigger the callback anytime your data changes so you should be resetting the `users` array inside the callback so you don't have duplicated and dirty data.
- Your function won't return the users with the data since firebase call is async. When you call `return users` you won't have the users array populated. I recommend you using `self.users = users` instead of returning it in the function. Otherwise, if you want to proceed with the current approach and return it, you should set a [completion handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240294/using-firebase-observesingleeventoftype-synchronously/38245971#38245971).

---

```
class func findUsers(text: String)->Void{
    ref.child("Users").queryOrderedByChild("name").queryStartingAtValue(text).queryEndingAtValue(text+"\u{f8ff}").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        var user = User()
        var users = [User]()
        for u in snapshot.children{
            user.name = u.value!["name"] as? String
            ...
            users.append(user)
        }
        self.users = users
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You just saved my life

Comment: I would say this is a correct solution, but it's not 100% efficient, for example it is not case-sensitive. If I search for "Jim", I get results, but searching "jim" gives me nothing. have a solution?

Comment: Hey @Wink, thanks for the comment and sorry for the late reply. I have added an update that should help.

Comment: I was pretty stuck here as well. The lowercase search string on the object model in firebase solved it for me. In a perfect world we'd use elastic search, but this gets the job done. Thanks!

Comment: This is still case sensitive. How can I make it so that if I search for JIM I get "jim" and "jimmy"?

Comment: @Outsider cast your searched string to lower case on the firebase query. Just make sure you have the names stored on lower case to.