# How to get data from firebase to another view controller

Tags: swift

I have a picker view to select an office and I have informations about them.

I added all informations about offices to firebase  
 `of
   firmname
        firm: "AAAA"
   officename
        office: "BBBB"
   phone
        phone: "23424234"
   user
        user: "a@a.com`

```
        let firmname = ["firm" : "AAAA"]
        let officename = ["office" : "BBBB"]
        let username = ["user" : "a@a.com"]
        let phone = ["phone" : "23424234"]

        let cref = root.child("of")

        let of = ["firmname": firmname, "officename": officename, "user": username,"phone": phone]

        cref.setValue(of)
```

I want to get for example just officename from another view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have a lot of strategies, a simple one would be to:

- create an Office object in your second View Controller

  `let myOffice = Office()`
- in the first view Controller, implement the `prepareForSegueWithIdentifier`method:

  ```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
      if (segue.identifier == "YourSegueIdentifierHere") {

          if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? YourSecondViewController {
              viewController.myOffice = of
          }

      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I don't have an office class. I hold informations in picker view class. If I select "AAAA" office for example , information about AAAA office will be added to firebase and when I go to another view controller I want to get the office name of AAAA office.

Comment: @BK. : My mistake, I obviously did not understand your problem. Maybe this link answers your question then : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274568/swift-firebase-search-in-database