# Swift -Firebase how to know if .childAdded is empty?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know when using `.value` I can check to see if there is anything there using `.exists()`

In this situation I’m running my queries in a `SearchController` and I need multiple results to get returned. Everything works fine when there are results but if there **aren’t any** I have no way of knowing.

How can I check if `.childAdded` returns nothing?

```
// if the user types in McDonalds and there are some then multiple will appear but if none then show a label that says “no results”

let searchText = searchController.searcchBar.text?.loweredCase() else { return }

Database.reference.child("restaurants")
    .queryOrdered(byChild:"restaurantName")
    .queryStarting(atValue: searchText)
    .queryEnding(atValue: searchText + “\u{f8ff}”)
    .observe( .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

          // no McDonalds appear so show a no results label
    })
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why you need to use .childAdded here instead of .value?

Comment: I created this a longggggggg time ago and I was just happy that it worked for my mvp. Now that  I want to transition to a more enhanced product everything needs to get refined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.childAdded` only fires for existing child nodes that match the query, you can't use it to detect when there are no matches. To detect if there are no matches, you'll need to use a `.value` listener and check `snapshot.exists`.

You can *either* use that in addition to your existing `.childAdded` listener (the Firebase client deduplicates the requests behind the scenes, so no extra data will be transferred, *or* you can use the `.value` listener to handle the results too. In the latter case you will need to [loop over `snapshot.children`](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+swift+loop+over+snapshot.children) to get to the individual result nodes.

Comment: In the latter case do I need to use **.observe** or **.observeSingleEvent**. I ask because it seems it’s pulling all the children at once that matches the results

Comment: You should use what you need. If you want to get the current values and all changes going forward, use `observe` (as you already did). If you only want to get the current values, use `observeSingleEvent`.

Comment: I’m going to follow this answer thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274936/4833705