# Swift: I am unable to pass back a variable from Firebase FIRAuth function to a declared variable from a parent funciton

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am a newb in swift and I've been trying to learn myself. I come across a problem which I am unsure on how to fix it. The code is as follow:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class UserLogin {

var email:String?
var password:String?

init(email:String, password:String){
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
}

func userLogin() -> String{
    var errorMsg:String = ""
    //Email & Password Integrity check
    if (email == ""){
        errorMsg = "Please enter your email"
    } else if (email?.rangeOfString("@") == nil || email?.rangeOfString(".") == nil){
        errorMsg = "Email is invalid"
    }else if (password == ""){
        errorMsg = "Please enter your password"
    }  else if (password?.characters.count < 8){
        errorMsg = "Password is invalid"
    }else{
        print("Logging In... with Email:\(email!) and Password:\(password!)")
        //Firebase Authentication Process"

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email!, password: password!){ (user, error) in
            // ...
            if (error != nil){
                let errorCode = error!.code
                if (errorCode == 17009){
                    errorMsg = "You have entered the wrong password"
                } else if (errorCode == 17011){
                    errorMsg = "Your email does not exist"
                } else if (errorCode == 17010) {
                    errorMsg = "You have tried to login too many times with the wrong credentials. Please try again later."
                } else {
                    print(error)
                }
            } else {
                print("User is Logged In")
                errorMsg = "You have successfully Logged In"
            }
        }
    }
    return errorMsg
}

}
```

Basically in my ViewController, I have a separate code that works like this

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: errorMsg, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This works fine for all my errorMsg within my userLogin func but for the few errorMsgs that are generated based on the error.code provided by FIRAuth, it does not appear.

I read around and figured it might be because FIRAuth is an Asynchronous Calls but I do not know how to work around it.

Sorry if this sounds really stupid but I've been figuring it out for the whole day but to no avail and it would be awesome to get some help from you guys.

**Addition:
I implemented the CompletionHandler as recommended but I don't understand why it did not work although it should... following is my code.**

UserLogin1.swift

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class UserLogin1 {

var email:String?
var password:String?

init(email:String, password:String){

    self.email = email
    self.password = password
}

func userLogin(completion:(message:String)->()) {

    var errorMsg:String = ""
    //Email & Password Integrity check
    if (email == ""){

        errorMsg = "Please enter your email"

    } else if (email?.rangeOfString("@") == nil || email?.rangeOfString(".") == nil){

        errorMsg = "Email is invalid"

    }else if (password == ""){

        errorMsg = "Please enter your password"

    }  else if (password?.characters.count < 8){

        errorMsg = "Password is invalid"

    }else if (errorMsg != ""){

        completion(message: errorMsg)

    }else{

        print("Logging In... with Email:\(email!) and Password:\(password!)")
        //Firebase Authentication Process"

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email!, password: password!){ (user, error) in
            // ...
            if (error != nil){

                let errorCode = error!.code

                if (errorCode == 17009){

                    errorMsg = "You have entered the wrong password"

                } else if (errorCode == 17011){

                    errorMsg = "Your email does not exist"

                } else if (errorCode == 17010) {

                    errorMsg = "You have tried to login too many times with the wrong credentials. Please try again later."

                } else {

                    print(error)

                }

            } else {
                print("User is Logged In")
                errorMsg = "You have successfully Logged In"
            }


        }
        completion(message: errorMsg)

    }

}

}
```

LoginViewController

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

//Properties
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

//Actions
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let email = self.emailTextField.text!
    let password = self.passwordTextField.text!

    let user = UserLogin1(email: email, password: password)

    user.userLogin(){ (message:String) in
        print(message)
    }


    }
```

Comment: You were right when speculated that the problem is that `signInWithEmail` is an async call. That means that when you return the message the signin function does not even finish processing. You will be able to do the trick using a [completion handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240294/using-firebase-observesingleeventoftype-synchronously/38245971#38245971) or just setting your message in `self. errorMsg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, I mentioned that you will have two possible solutions. The best choice will depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. But I'm sure you can make it work with any of them.

### With [Completion Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240294/using-firebase-observesingleeventoftype-synchronously/38245971#38245971)

```
func userLogin(completion:(message:String)->()){
    var errorMsg:String = ""
    if (email == ""){
    ...
    //check if found any errors yet
    }else if (errorMsg != ""){
        completion(errorMsg)
    } else {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email!, password: password!){ (user, error) in
            if (error != nil){
            ...
            } else {
                errorMsg = "You have successfully Logged In"
            }
            completion(errorMsg)
        }
    }
}

userLogin(){ (message:String) in
    // this will only be called when userLogin trigger completion(errorMsg)...
    print(message)
}
```

### With Self

```
func userLogin() -> Void{
    var errorMsg:String = ""
    if (email == ""){
    ...
    //check if found any error yet
    }else if (errorMsg != ""){
        self.errorMsg = errorMsg
    } else {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email!, password: password!){ (user, error) in
            if (error != nil){
            ...
            } else {
                errorMsg = "You have successfully Logged In"
            }
            self.errorMsg = errorMsg
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi adolfosrs! thanks for the response. i really appreciated it. I tried your methods.. for the second part with self, it keeps returning me UserLogin do not have a member of errorMsg.. and for the second method, i implemented it as follows, although it is not returning me any errors, when i print(message) nothing is showing at all. I really don't know where I am doing wrong... I leave the implemented codes below and if possible, can i trouble you to take some time to look through it and help me see why? thanksss!

Comment: @JiacaiLau did u debbug it? Is `userLogin` being called at all? Try replacing `completion(message: errorMsg)` to `completion(errorMsg)`.

Comment: I've tested and userLogin is being called. weirdly, if I entered the right email and password, it is still able to print("Logging in...with email...) and print("User is logged in") but the errorMsg is not populating. If i change it to completion(errorMsg) it returns an error of "Missing argument label 'message' in call"

Comment: oh I figured it out. I think the position of my completion(message: errorMsg) is wrong! Thanks adolfosrs. You are of great help!!

Comment: @JiacaiLau yes it is. it should be inside of the firebase callback. (one `}` above). U welcome!

Comment: @JiacaiLau The way u just paste in the other answer wont work in some cases. take a better look into my answer you will see that you havent set the completion call in the right position. Also, there is no need of adding another answer since this one is enought for solving your problem.

Comment: Alright. i will look into it further. thanks and sorry for reposting.. im new around here!

Comment: @JiacaiLau no problem. I'm glad u made progress! let me know if you need any further help. And please set the answer to accepted if it helped to solve it. :) Regards.