# Retrieve String value from function with closure in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, closures, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve a string value from Firebase in order to get each username with an unique UID that is passed to the function, which returns the username of the user. However - since the firebase `ObserveEvent` is in `closures`, I can't return any value back because the actions happens **asynchronous**(?). I was wondering if it was a way of accomplishing this?

The function looks like this:

```
func GetUsername(uid:String) -> String {
    var username = String()
    firebase.child("Users").child(uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

        username = snapshot.value!["Username"] as! String

    }

    return username
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but I want to be able to get the data by doing a GetUsername("whatevertheidmightbe"). Ideas?

Comment: Just add a completion handler

Comment: @LeoDabus Like this? func GetUsername(uid:String, callback: (String) -> String) {     firebase.child("Users").child(uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
        
        callback(snapshot.value!["DisplayName"] as! String)
        
    }
    
}

I can't really make it work, somehow..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Firebase observeSingleEventOfType synchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240294/using-firebase-observesingleeventoftype-synchronously)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning method object from inside block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267865/returning-method-object-from-inside-block)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create completion handler like this

```
func GetUsername(uid:String , completion: (String) -> ()) {
    firebase.child("Users").child(uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
    if let username = snapshot.value!["Username"] as? String
        completion(username)
    }
    else {
        completion("")
    }
}
```

And call function like this way

```
self.GetUsername(str) { (name) -> () in
    if name.characters.count > 0 {
         print(name)
    }
    else {
         print("Not found")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question; would it be possible to make it a return type of String? (So I can easily call GetUsername and retrieve the username in a string format?

Comment: Yes, I know - but I was just asking if it was possible to make the return type of type String? As I can see that right now it is of Void(). I don't have much experience with closures, so for all I know this might also be impossible..?

Comment: @askaale I have edited answer now you get batter idea about remove `void` so you can clearly understand it. Here we are passing the string value in completion handler.

Comment: Yeah, as far as I am concerned - you can't return a value of type string (in return name) format?

Comment: At least I can't, while trying to print it in the console (without printing it from the function, but using return instead).

Comment: I don't understand what you try to say.

Comment: What I basically mean is that instead of having to call a function and make it print the value, I want to make it a return type - to immediately return the string, instead of having to call it like a function, and and then print the value. Like (uid:String) -> String, and obtain the username by doing GetUsername("uid") (which returns just a string.

Comment: This is not possible and answer of this question you have already given because of async behaviour of firebase.

Comment: yeah okay - I just wanted to be 100% sure. Thank you very much for your help. I accepted your answer now.